# How can I redirect WebDriver to new page and back for each found link avoiding StaleElementReferenceException?

Tags: java, selenium, exception, web-scraping, webdriver

So, the simplest example would be fetching data from google search engine results.

Example code:

```
void test() {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("pizza"); // type pizza in search field

    driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click(); // perform search

    // for every header link in search results page
    for(WebElement link : driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class = 'r']/a"))) {

        link.click(); // click the link

        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // fetch page url or something else

        driver.navigate().back(); // go back to search results

    }
}
```

But, on second iteration, exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element
>   reference of  stale: either the element is no longer attached to
>   the DOM or the page has been refreshed

That's because the remaining links are invalidated the moment i click one of them. How can somehow iterate over them all for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` loop with index for this and relocate the list each iteration

```
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class = 'r']/a"))
    count = links.size();
    link.get(i).click(); // click the link
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); // fetch page url or something else
    driver.navigate().back(); // go back to search results
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code block to avoid **StaleElementReferenceException** I would suggest a change in the approach as follows :

- Create a `List` out of your search results, extract the `href` attribute and strore them in a new `List`.
- Open each `href` in a new `TAB`, switch to the newly opened `TAB` and perform the required operations.
- Once you complete the operations on the new tab, `Close` the `TAB` and switch back to the main `TAB`.
- Here is the sample code block to perform the above mentions steps :

  ```
  List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='srg']/div[@class='g']//h3/a"));
  ArrayList<String> href_list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(WebElement element:my_list)
      href_list.add(element.getAttribute("href"));
  for(String myhref:href_list)
  {
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", myhref); 
      //switch to the required TAB, perform the operations, close and switch back to main TAB
      //For demonstration I didn't switch/close any of the TABS
  }
  ```